# error classLoader parameter on Struts 1.2.4

Tags: java, struts-1

My project is worked on Struts 1.2.4.
I want to use Filter to prevent input classLoader parameters. but it seems that struts 1.2.4 did not support for Filter, right?

Do you know any solution to prevent classLoader parameters in Struts 1.2.4, please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Filters are part of the underlying JEE framework and have nothing to do with Struts. Of course you can use filters with Struts. You could also create a custom request processor.

Comment: I don't understand...what do you want to achieve and why do you want to prevent class loader parameters? Also, what class loader do you want to prevent exactly?